# How to delete this string from a file using sed or perl?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, perl

I want to delete this string:

> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10"

in below file:

> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"centos\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCV9sc7lTrpAJb1UARLmNA08XD8Dy0hGJiX1E5qYk8MkH36xbBtcO6xeuncFr619pu+R/08jkYn9GIXlgPzD9THUpEI+m/OSp5nVPgIamiN7LudOSks6zwk9THkxeSmW95KNEHW5h8Y8MoB0wXzGdr0yiV32nLmvyG18JU6

Comment: @quixotic: actually it looks like `authorized_keys` which can have options as shown and normally does NOT have hostname/IP

Answer (score 0):

The file is an `authorized_keys` file for SSH, often found in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. It has a number of fields, and the field you would like to remove is the first optional "options" field.

The second field is the "keytype" field, which will have one of the values `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`,
     `ecdsa-sha2-nistp384`, `ecdsa-sha2-nistp521`, `ssh-ed25519`, `ssh-dss` or
     `ssh-rsa`, according to the `sshd` manual.

We may use this fact to remove the options field:

```
sed -E 's/^.* (ecdsa-sha2-(nistp384|nistp521)|ssh-(ed25519|dss|rsa))/\1/' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys >~/.ssh/authorized_keys.new &&
mv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.new ~/.ssh/authorized_keys &&
chmod go-rwx ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Or, you may use `sed -i ...` to change the file in-place if you know how this usually works on your Unix (the `-i` flag works *slightly* differently in different implementations of `sed`).

The `sed` editing command `s/^.* (ecdsa-sha2-(nistp384|nistp521)|ssh-(ed25519|dss|rsa))/\1/` will match the extended regular expression `^.* (ecdsa-sha2-(nistp384|nistp521)|ssh-(ed25519|dss|rsa))` and replace the matched text with the key type found on the line. The expression matches anything from the beginning of each line of input, up to, and including, one of the valid key types.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -i 's/your_string//g' filename
```

You will likely need to escape some punctuation in your_string.

Comment: Or more easily `sed -i 's/^.* ssh-rsa/ssh-rsa/' file` (given we know it's an RSA key; if not there are about a dozen possibilities)